# value error too many values to unpack(expected 2)

Tags: python, numpy

i have a featured vector X_train for set of images  of 64*64 pixels

so system stores image in RGB pattern each of 64*64 pixels

so reshaping image to featured vector gives:
 64*64*3(RGB for each image),no.of images  = (12288,209)

where 209 is number of training examples

here is the part of my code where i am getting error

```
           print(X_train.shape)
     ----> w,b  =  np.zeros((X_train.shape[0],1))

          Output:(12288,209)
          ValueError:  too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What are you expecting in `w` and `b`?

Comment: Vishnudev i am trying to intialize w,b with zeros of dimenisons(no.of features,1) = (12288,1)

Comment: You can't. How can you assign `12288x1` sized array to something of different shape like these two variables?

Comment: ok tq ,then how can we intialize w,b to 0 arrays to both of them in a line

Comment: Is `w,b` a single variable or two variables? Do you know about unpacking?

Comment: i am soory i am new i dont know aboutt unpacking

Comment: could you just explain breifly

Comment: `w, b = [1, 2]` then `w = 1` and `b = 2`. Basic unpacking. You can't do `w, b = [1, 2, 3]`, it will give `too many values to unpack`.

Comment: w,b are two variables

Comment: tq so much ,so how can we assign 12288 aaray of zeros to both variables at a time?

Comment: is it possible or we want to do it in individual statements

Comment: I have added it as an answer @sri

Comment: Don't try to assign both in one line.  Each variable requires its own array.

Answer (score 1):

To assign to both variables at same time, don't use unpacking,

```
w = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0],1))
b = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0],1))
```

Comment: Careful.  That's giving 2 different names to the same array.  Changes to `w` are changes to `b`.